# I want to open a json file in python but got an error. It said No such file or directory

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file-not-found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxccM.png)

I wrote the code like this:

```
intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())
```

Comment: Are you sure the file intents.json is in the same directory as the script you are running? Dir: D:\L.I.S.A\

Comment: The file does not exist in your current working directory. It is possible your working directory is not what you expect.

Comment: use `import os;os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

Check your intents.json file is in the same folder on which you python file is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use, for example, the `os` builf-in module to check on the existence of file and `os.path` for path manipulation. Check the official doc at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

```
import os

file = 'intents.json'
# location of the current directory
w_dir = os.path.abspath('.'))
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(w_dir, file)):
    with open(file, 'r') as fd:
       fd.read()
else:
    print('Such file does not exist here "{}"...'.format(w_dir))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try opening the file using the normal file operation and then use json.load or json.loads to parse the data as per your needs. I may be unfamiliar with this syntax to the best of my knowledge your syntax is wrong.

You can open the file like this:

```
f = open(file_name)
```

Then parse the data:

```
data = json.load(f)
```

You can refer to this link for more info and reference

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-json-file-using-python/